# Passing class attribute to function

Tags: c++, oop

I wanted to write battleship game, but I got some troubles when it comes to OOP aspect... First of all, I got `Battlefield` class

```
class Battlefield
{
private:
    string **array;
public:
    Battlefield();
    ~Battlefield();
    void createBattlefield();
    void drawBattlefield();
    string getArray();
};
```

> Constructor

```
    Battlefield::Battlefield()
{   
    array = new string*[12];
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        array[i] = new string[12];
    }
}
```

> getArray()

```
string Battlefield::getArray()
{
    return **array;
}
```

Second class is `Game`, where till now I got just one method `shoot()`

```
void Game::shoot(string **array)
{       
    char row;
    int column;

        cout << endl << "Row (A, B, ... , J): ";
        do{
            cin >> row;
            if (islower(row)) row = toupper(row);
            if (row > 'J' || row < 'A'){
                cout << "Row out of range!" << endl << "Try again: ";
            }

        } while (row > 'J' || row < 'A');

        cout << "Column (1, 2, ... , 10): ";
        do{
            cin >> column;
            if (column > 10 || column < 1){
                cout << "Column out of range!" << endl << "Try again: ";
            }
        } while (column > 10 || column < 1);

        array[(int)(row - 64)][column] = "[.]";
}
```

Which basicly just places [.] in array[x][y]
But Im having troubles getting this to work together in `main`

```
int main()
{
    Battlefield array;
    Game game;

    array.createBattlefield();

    game.shoot(array.getArray());
}
```

last line causes

> error C2664: 'void Game::shoot(std::string **)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'std::string **'

Comment: The error message should be very clear if you just read it. Think about what `getArray` ***really*** returns. Hint: It's not an array.

Comment: On a slightly related note, if you allocate a fixed size number of strings and arrays of strings, then I recommend [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

Comment: Don't use `new` before you have at least 20 years of experience in C++.

Comment: You might be better off creating a `Cell` enum which has states like `Unknown, Water, Ship` and then declare your array to be of type `std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `getArray()` returns a string, i. e. a **1D char array** and `Game::shoot()` expects a **3D char array**, hence the error. If I understood you right and you want to return a 2D battlefield, like in [Battleship game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game)), you have to create `char**` or `vector<vector<char>>` or `vector<string>`, all of which will be 2D char arrays.
2. The `string** array` is not a 2D matrix, it's a 3D, as far as I understand.
3. Don't use cpp-string and c-style pointers together, it's a really error-prone approach, i. e. `string**` is an abomination, you should delete it right away and never use constructs like this again.
4. If you want to pass big objects like 2D matrices, you should really avoid copying and prefer passing them by pointer, by reference or use move constructors.
5. Avoid using new, use objects on stack or let `boost`, `Qt` or `std::unique_pointer` manage the memory for you.
6. Why is `row` a `char` and a `column` is of type `int`? Do you try to save 16 bits of memory here? It is not worth it and is very confusing.
7. Try to avoid too general names like `array`, trust me, when you will have over 5k lines of code, it will be very hard to remember which array it is. Use this opportunity to make your code more readable.
8. I think, the `Game` class should create the `Battlefield` class inside itself, maybe it can contain a vector of `Battlefield`s, if you assume, that more than one `Battlefield` can be in game, but it's generally up to you.
9. What you do in `Battlefield`'s constructor is an absolutely unnecessary piece of code, imo. Vectors and strings handle their size for you, you can add size constrains as members of `Battlefield` class, just to keep your game logic straight, but constraining vector to use only n elements, when it potentially can hold any numbers of it is like breaking its leg and forcing it to dance.
10. In spite of all this little mistakes, you're doing great! If you have any other questions, don't hesitate to ask.

So, this is a sample of what you could write:

```
class Battlefield
{
private:
    vector<string> mField;
public:
    Battlefield();
    ~Battlefield();
    void createBattlefield();
    void drawBattlefield();
    vector<string>& getArray();
};

Battlefield::Battlefield() {}

void Game::shoot(vector<string>& field)
{       
    int row;
    int column;
    // your logic goes here
}

int main()
{
    Battlefield field;
    Game game;

    field.createBattlefield();

    game.shoot(array.getArray());
}
```